# Slick/HikariCP giving "too many connections" instead of timeouts

Tags: mysql, slick, hikaricp, amazon-rds

I'm using `Slick3.1.1` + `HikariCP2.5.1` to connect to an AWS `t2.medium` MySql instance. The AWS docs say that `t2.medium` can have 312 maximum connections. My configuration file is:

```
rdsConfig = {
  url = "jdbc:mysql://mydb.........us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/owlschema"  

  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  connectionPool = HikariCP
  maxConnections = 222         # <<<<< ie make this < 312.
  keepAliveConnection = true
  properties = {
    user = "me"
    password = "mydarksecret"
  }
  numThreads = 40    
}
```

When I hit it with a heavy load I start getting 'too many connections' errors:

```
    17:05:40.708 DEBUG [] [rdsConfig connection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - rdsConfig - Cannot acquire connection from data source
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor59.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
...
```

I'm confused about this. From the docs I thought that it should never be trying to get more than the 222 connections I specified, which would never exceed the AWS limit. I was expecting to get timeouts under a heavy load, but not 'too many connections' errors. So what does `maxConnections` do? Thanks.

Comment: Does it also instantly happen if you set `minConnections` to `222`? (let's just be sure that the problem is being on Slick part reserving more connections than specified; rather than MySQL throwing exception far below the limit)

Comment: It doesn't instantly happen. The log shows that it opens connections one by one, and if the load's not too heavy it never has a problem. It's only if the load gets too high that it opens too many connections.

Comment: You mean even when you set `minConnections = 222` ?

Comment: You're right. (I originally misread your comment). I've explained in my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it. As suggested by @Pawel Dolega above, I also set `minConnections = 222` as an experiment. On starting the application I immediately started getting `too many connections` errors, even without a load. It turned out to be my bug: I was actually opening multiple separate Database instances as I was using the following trait in every class that needed db access:

```
trait dbCore {
  val db = Database.forConfig("rdsConfig")
}
```

So each class was using its own separate cap of 222 connections. Changing this trait to an object instead fixed the bug - now all classes use the same singleton Database instance so the `maxConnections` cap is properly respected.

Comment: I appreciate for you feedback. It helped me a lot.